# Drop Down menu restriction

Tags: drop-down-menu

So... I've created two dropdowns on the subject of music. The Dropdowns are Genre and artist. What im trying to do is.. for example if you chose Rap in Genre.. Artist will only display Artists related to Rap.

so here if i chose Rap, on the next drop down how can i make it so the user can only see Iggy Azalea and not any other artist that relates to other genres(but they will be hiden)?

```
      <select name="Genre"></option>
      <option value="Default">[choose genre]</option>
      <option value="Rap">Rap</option>
      </select>

      <select name="Artist"></option>
      <option value="Default">[choose artist]</option>
      <option value="IggyAzalea">Iggy Azalea</option>
      <option value="ArianaGrand">Ariana Grande</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: what have you tried ? Do you plan to do this server-side or client-side ? is you data loaded dynamically through AJAX or not ? Long story short : please read and learn the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: ive tried doing through javascript but maybe ive done incorrectly, server and client side

Comment: Thanks that is very helpfull... 3 questions and 1 link, 1 answer and most probably not even a look to the page provided. That is not how you're supposed to ask questions here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jquery like this.

Give the Class Name to the 'Artist' drop-down `option` tag = Parent Genre Name(to which Artist belong to). 
And hide and show those option on change of Genre.
Check following example for clarification.

**HTML**

```
<select name="Genre" id="Genre"></option>
<option value="Default">[choose genre]</option>
<option value="Rap">Rap</option>
<option value="Example">Example</option>
<option value="OtherExample">OtherExample</option>
</select>

<select name="Artist" id="Artist"></option>
<option value="Default">[choose artist]</option>
<option class="Rap artist" value="IggyAzalea">Iggy Azalea</option>
<option class="Rap artist" value="RapOne">RapOne</option>
<option class="Example artist" value="Example Option 1">Example Option 1</option>
<option class="Example artist" value="Example Option 2">Example Option 2</option>
<option class="OtherExample artist" value="OtherExample Option 1">OtherExample Option 1</option>
<option class="OtherExample artist" value="OtherExample Option 2">OtherExample Option 2</option>
<option class="artist" value="ArianaGrand">Ariana Grande</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
    $('#Genre').on('change', function() {       
        $('.artist').hide();
        $('.'+$(this).val()).show();
    });        
</script>
```